# Updating a row number which has been randomised

Tags: php

So I currently have a random number being generated in PHP and I want to know how I go about updating the row number in my selected table. Code below:

```
$sxiq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `starting_eleven` WHERE `team_id`=$uid");
$sxir = mysql_fetch_row($sxiq);
$first = rand(1,11);
$stat_changed = rand(11,31);
$up_or_down = rand(1,2);
if ($up_or_down == 1) {
    $player_name = explode(" ", $sxir[$first]);
    $fn = $player_name[0];
    $ln = $player_name[1];
    $statq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `first_name`=$fn AND `last_name`=$ln AND `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
    $statr = mysql_fetch_row($statq);
    $stat = $statr[0];
}
```

I would like to update the row $stat_changed from the database, but I'm not sure if this is possible without doing a long if statement, telling the code if $stat_changed = 13 $stat = pace or something along those lines, but if this is the way it must be done then I'll have to.  Just thought I'd see if there was any other simpler ways of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $stat_changed is not a row, so how can you update it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stat_changed == 13) {
    //insert UPDATE statement here
}
```